# Append content to slice into a nested struct does not work

Tags: go, struct, append, slice

I have two nested structs like this:

```
type Block struct {
    ID       string
    Contents []string
}

type Package struct {
    Name   string
    Blocks []Block
}
```

Original package (`p`) does not change when I try to append a new Content in a specific block.

```
for _, b := range p.Blocks {
    if b.ID == "B1" {
        fmt.Println("Adding a new content")
        b.Contents = append(b.Contents, "c3")
    }
}
```

Example:

https://play.golang.org/p/5hm6RjPFk8o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because this line:

```golang
for _, b := range p.Blocks {
```

creates a *copy* of each element in the slice, and in this case this means creating a copy of each `Block` in the slice. So when you then make the changes in the loop body, you are making them to the copy of the `Block`, instead of to the `Block` in the slice.

If you instead use the index to get a pointer to each `Block`, e.g.

```golang
for i := range p.Blocks {
    b := &p.Blocks[i]
    // modify b ...
}
```

it works as expected:

https://play.golang.org/p/h_nXEX9oWRT

Alternatively, you can make the changes to the copy (as in your original code), and then copy the modified value back to the slice:

```golang
for i, b := range p.Blocks {
    // modify b ...
    p.Blocks[i] = b
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kVHTk-OTyC3

Even further, you could instead store pointers to `Block` in the slice (instead of the `Block` themselves), in which case your loop would be making a copy of the pointer, which is a valid way to access the `Block` the original pointers points to:

https://go.dev/play/p/I9-EyV_iCNS

Answer (score 1):

When you are looping over a slice, each of the individual values retrieved from the slice is a copy of the corresponding element in the slice. So to modify the element in the slice, instead of the copy, you can access the element directly using the indexing expression. Or you can use pointers. Note that pointers are also copied but the copied pointer will point to the same address as the element in the slice and therefore can be used to directly modify the same data.

---

You can use indexing:

```golang
for i := range p.Blocks {
    if p.Blocks[i].ID == "B1" {
        fmt.Println("Adding a new content")
        p.Blocks[i].Contents = append(p.Blocks[i].Contents, "c3")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/di175k18YQ9

---

Or you can use pointers:

```golang
type Block struct {
    ID       string
    Contents []string
}

type Package struct {
    Name   string
    Blocks []*Block
}

for _, b := range p.Blocks {
    if b.ID == "B1" {
        fmt.Println("Adding a new content")
        b.Contents = append(b.Contents, "c3")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1RjWlCZkhYv